# Mod Rewrite URL with several parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently having a hard time rewriting a URL. The .htaccess file already contains some rules so I need to add a new rule to the existing ones. The current rule includes redirecting to https:// if http:// was used (except if the URL contains 'php05142013'). Here's the current content of the .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://mycreditstatus.co.za/404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.co\.za$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(php01202015) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite\.co\.za$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(php01202015) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://mycreditstatus.co.za [L,R=301]
```

What I want to achieve now in addition to the current rules, is to rewrite the URL like `https://mysite.co.za/3pv/XnAnr3ABtgo%3D/3irqrHe%2FQJE%3D` into `https://mysite.co.za/index.php?action=register&auth=1&p=3pv&eid=XnAnr3ABtgo%3D&us=3irqrHe%2FQJE%3D`

I've been trying something like `^/([^A-Za-z0-9.)(/\\%-])/([^A-Za-z0-9.)(/\\%-])/([^A-Za-z0-9.)(/\\%-])/([^A-Za-z0-9.)(/\\%-])/?$    index.php?action=register&auth=1&p=$1&eid=$2&us=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}    [NC,L]    # Process product requests` and I'm sure it's wrong. I'm new to mod rewrite and I find it very confusing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this new rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=register&auth=1&p=$1&eid=$2&us=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This should be added at the bottom? It does not seem to work.

Comment: Thanks. I modified it into RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=register&auth=1&p=$1&eid=$2&us=$3 [QSA,L] and it's now close to the output that I wanted. The URL became https://mysite.co.za/index.php?action=register&auth=1&p=3pv/XnAnr3ABtgo&eid==&us=3irqrHe however, it should be &p=3pv&eid=XnAnr3ABtgo%3D=&us=3irqrHe%2FQJE%3D

Comment: What is the full URL you entered in browser?

Comment: You need to have `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode` in Apache config to pass `%2F` as is to your htaccess